# How can I start an activity when the user clicks on a ListItem?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, listviewitem

Here is my code. I'd like to pass a boolean to the activity i want to start.

```
private void setupUI() {
        setContentView(R.layout.more_tab_activity);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.streamListView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , streams));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                //start the streamactivity
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at any tutorials?

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, StreamActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", true);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: make sure you add the new activity to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: and if the Activity has already been created try
    startActivityIfNeeded();

Comment: I've never even seen startactivityifneeded. It sounds like it has a pretty dubious use case.

Comment: thx. i had to use getApplicationContext(), and pass a string of the package name for new Intent() that was tripping me up.

Comment: Well we have no idea if he activity has intent filters or anything.